# How to sort this kind of file with "sort"

Tags: linux, sorting

I have this file I would like to sort with the order "sort" in linux (very beginner)

[image]

I tried sort without parameter, without success.
I tried sort -n, without success.

Is it because there are a lot of "blanks" on each line to be sorted ?

How to sort this kind of file ?

**EDIT :**

I would like the result in the same file. that's perhaps why it does not work ?

example :

```
3703900012346016020810100200             0992           
3703900012346016022210100600             0992           
3703900012346016022310100600             0992           
3703900012346016022410100600             0992           
3703900012346016020210170100             0992           
3703900012346016020312600700             0992           
3703900012346016020512910200             0992           
3703900012346016021013600200             0992           
3703900012346016020113690100             0992           
3703900012346016021213700900             0992           
3703900012346016020813800200             0992           
3703900012346016021314100500             0992           
3703900012346016020614200200             0992           
3703900012346016020714290200             0992           
3703900012346016021414400300             0992           
3703900012346016021514700400             0992           
3703900012346016021614780600             0992           
3703900012346016021714790800             0992           
3703900012346016021895200800             0992
```

Comment: Would help if you had a plain-text version of the data here.

Comment: look for sed or awk based on the number of characters

Comment: hi , it s a plain-test version. Each line is 56 charac length. and ther is no header, no separator, etc.. only text.

Comment: @user2672338 What Yam means, is provide in your question a plain text version of it that we can use while trying solutions ourselves, as opposed to an image of plain text like you currently have

Comment: I added the text in the post. Thanks

Comment: does `sort -k9,20 input.txt`  solve your problem?

Comment: @FredrikPihl: That sorts on *fields* 9 through 20, where fields are delimited by whitespace.  The effect seems to be that the sort key is the whole line, which happens to work here because all lines have the same first 8 characters.  But if you change the first character of the first given line to 4, your solution doesn't behave as desired.

Comment: I understand my pb. It is a batch and I would liket to replace the sorted file with itself. Something like that : 'sort -k9,20 input.txt > input.txt'

Comment: I tried this without success : sort -k9,20 file -o file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `sort -n -k 1.10,1.23 filename`.

-n is a numeric sort. -k describes where the key is. Look at sorts man page. In my example I describe a key from columns 10-23. You may not need -n since it looks like all the characters are between 0-9.

Comment: And use `sort -n -k 1.10,1.23 filename -o filename` to do it inplace.

Comment: Might want to check those boundaries again with the highlighted area in the picture.

Comment: hi , i tried it without success. But I wonder if it is the -o option which can trigger a problem. But unfortunately it is a batch and i cannot see the result of the sort.